# Python: How to label nodes of a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a graph that shows a bunch of bubbles, similar to this figure:
[image: bubbles]
I would like to change a few things in this figure, however: First of all, the annotation is suppossed to go in the center of each bubble. Secondly, I would like the bubbles to be separated a bit further and then have an arrow point from every left bubble to its right neighbour.

What I am asking is: Is there an easy way to do this?

So far, I am using PatchCollection to draw these bubbles. And I have a feeling this is not the easiest way:

```
    myList = [20, 15, 10, 5, 0, 1, 6, 11, 16, 2^, 22, 17, 12, 7, 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 24, 19, 14, 9, 4, 8]
    x_coords = list(range(len(myList))

    plt.figure()
    axes = plt.gca()

    for i in range(0, len(myList)):
        x = x_coords[i]
        y = 4
        circle = plt.Circle((x,y), radius=0.5, fill=False, edgecolor='k')
        patches.append(circle)
        plt.annotate(myList[i], (x,y))

    collection = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
    axes.add_collection(collection)
    axes.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.show()
```

I know how to add an arrow through annotation as well. But is there a way to center the labels, i.e. the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

For every patch, you need to include

```
plt.text(x_center, y_center, 'yourLabelGoesHere')
```

---

You might have to write a function that can compute `x_center` and `y_center` dynamically. From the graph that you shared, I guess `y_center` can probably be a constant though.